# 'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found after upgrade to 0.60

Tags: xcode, react-native, appdelegate

Unable to build the react-native app after upgrade to 0.60 got an error 'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found

> AppDelegate.h file

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface AppDelegate() : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, RCTBridgeDelegate.h>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

Comment: Have you run 'cd ios pod install` command ?

Comment: Yes I have run cd ios pod install

Answer (score 1):

If you are using cocoapods and in this case you are,if you are trying to build from Xcode you should build from the `.xcworkspace` file and NOT from the `.xcodeproj`. This will propably solve your problem.